# How to set button height to viewport height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I do this to get viewport height and set button height to it

```
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
var viewPortHeightStr = `\"${viewportHeight}px\"`
document.getElementById("button").style.height = viewPortHeightStr
console.log('viewPortHeightStr = '+viewPortHeightStr) // prints "750px"
```

Console logs `"750px"` but height of button is unaffected, however this works

```
document.getElementById("button").style.height = "750px"
```

Why?

Here is button tag

```
<button id="button" class="btn-basic">x</button>
```

Comment: You need 100% height of vport?

Comment: I'm just learning how to design proportionally to view port, so no I don't

Answer (score 1):

It is easy in CSS. Use:

```
height: 100vh;
```

This means 100% of the viewport height.

In your code, the problem seems to be:

```
var viewPortHeightStr = `\"${viewportHeight}px\"`
// change it to:
var viewPortHeightStr = viewportHeight + 'px';
```

Snippet:

```js
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
var viewPortHeightStr = viewportHeight + 'px';
document.getElementById("button").style.height = viewPortHeightStr
console.log('viewPortHeightStr = '+viewPortHeightStr) // prints "750px"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button" class="btn-basic">x</button>
```

Comment: Great thanks, if you could explain why my solution doesn't work, that would technically answer my question

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
document.getElementById("button").style.height(viewPortHeightStr);
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById("button").style.height = viewPortHeightStr
```